# "@IgniteInstanceResource var ignite: Ignite" in services is null

Tags: java, scala, ignite

[Updated] As the title says, the injection feature of ignite is not working on my services.

My service interface code is trivial

```
trait FeederService extends Service with Logging{

  @IgniteInstanceResource  protected var ignite: Ignite = _
  // log.info(s"ignite instance: ${ignite.toString}")

  def runNewFeeders(qty: Int)
}
```

Here's my service implementation

```
  override def init(ctx: ServiceContext): Unit = {

    log.info(s"Initializing service ${ctx.name()}") 
    log.info(s"ignite instance: ${ignite.toString}")
  }
```

This code crashes because the ignite object is null.

My service deployment, in the main, is the following (I can, of course, access the Ignite object in the main method)

```
ignite.services(clientGroup).deployNodeSingleton("feeder-swarm",
new FeederServiceImpl())
```

Don't know if related, but clientGroup is extracted with

```
val clientGroup = ignite.cluster().forAttribute("client", "true")
```

Because I do not use the Ignite client definition for my nodes (they are all servers on the Ignite point of view)

Any help?
Thanks

Comment: Can you upload your project to GitHub? I tried running your code and it works as expected. `Ignite` instance is injected and printed in the `init()` method.

Comment: Yep, I also checked that, `@IgniteInstanceResource` works OK with Scala traits. Need a full reproducer to help you.

Comment: Try to use @(IgniteInstanceResource @field) annotation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to access an `Ignite` instance before it was injected.

`Ignite` can only be injected after the object is constructed, but your instance initializer tries to use it (`${ignite.toString}`) and fails.

Move your `log.info` call to the `init` method, it'll work.

Comment: Hi Stanislav Lukyanov, thanks but even after removing the log I cannot access the Ignite obj nor in the init nor in the execution of the service. 
It's like it is not injecting at all